# Magento Redirect customer to checkout page

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, login, redirect-url

I try to find a solution, I have a special case, Let's say that my customers add something in cart, then they need to login or register. So I want to do something like this: after login/registration if they have a product in cart to be redirected to the checkout page, if they don't have a product in cart to be redirected to the my account page. Is this possible? Or exist for Magento a extension like this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, its possible.

**OPTION 1:** Using event observer, add below code in your `config.xml`:

```
<events>
    <customer_login>
        <observers>
            <redirection>
                <class>redirection/observer_customer</class>
                <method>customerLogin</method>
            </redirection>
        </observers>
    </customer_login> 
</events>
```

And in your `customerLogin()` of `Namespace_Extension_Model_Observer_Customer` class you need to check if current cart has any item then redirect to shopping cart page like -

```
public function customerLogin(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{    
    if (Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getItemsCount()){  
        $_session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
        $_session->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCartUrl());
    }
}
```

**OPTION 2:** Another option is to override `Mage_Customer` controller.
In your module `config.xml` file add below code:

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <customer>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <moduleidentifier_customer before="Mage_Customer">YourModule_Customer</moduleidentifier_customer>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </customer>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

After that you have to create account controller inside your module `controllers` directory and placed below code in your controller class:

```
class Yourmodule_Customer_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController
{

   /**
     * Overriding defaults redirect URL 
     * Define target URL and redirect customer after logging in
     */
    protected function _loginPostRedirect()
    {    
        $session = $this->_getSession();

        if($session->isLoggedIn() && Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getItemsCount()){
            $_session->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCartUrl());
        }
        else{
            if (!$session->getBeforeAuthUrl() || $session->getBeforeAuthUrl() == Mage::getBaseUrl()) {
                // Set default URL to redirect customer to
                $session->setBeforeAuthUrl($this->_getHelper('customer')->getAccountUrl());
                // Redirect customer to the last page visited after logging in
                if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
                    if (!Mage::getStoreConfigFlag(
                        Mage_Customer_Helper_Data::XML_PATH_CUSTOMER_STARTUP_REDIRECT_TO_DASHBOARD
                    )) {
                        $referer = $this->getRequest()->getParam(Mage_Customer_Helper_Data::REFERER_QUERY_PARAM_NAME);
                        if ($referer) {
                            // Rebuild referer URL to handle the case when SID was changed
                            $referer = $this->_getModel('core/url')
                                ->getRebuiltUrl( $this->_getHelper('core')->urlDecodeAndEscape($referer));
                            if ($this->_isUrlInternal($referer)) {
                                $session->setBeforeAuthUrl($referer);
                            }
                        }
                    } else if ($session->getAfterAuthUrl()) {
                        $session->setBeforeAuthUrl($session->getAfterAuthUrl(true));
                    }
                } else {
                    $session->setBeforeAuthUrl( $this->_getHelper('customer')->getLoginUrl());
                }
            } else if ($session->getBeforeAuthUrl() ==  $this->_getHelper('customer')->getLogoutUrl()) {
                $session->setBeforeAuthUrl( $this->_getHelper('customer')->getDashboardUrl());
            } else {
                if (!$session->getAfterAuthUrl()) {
                    $session->setAfterAuthUrl($session->getBeforeAuthUrl());
                }
                if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
                    $session->setBeforeAuthUrl($session->getAfterAuthUrl(true));
                }
            }
        }
        $this->_redirectUrl($session->getBeforeAuthUrl(true));       
    }
}
```

> **Note**: Compare your `Mage_Customer_AccountController` class
>   `_loginPostRedirect()` method with above mentioned
>   `_loginPostRedirect()` method for difference. Change `module`,
>   `method`, `configuration node`, etc. according to your module.

Let me know if you have any issue regarding approach.

Comment: thank you so much, is there any way to put this in an extension please?

Comment: You may use any third party extension for `Customer Redirection` and put your redirection code inside their code. Magento Connect has soo many extension for redirect login which you get on [this link](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?q=login+redirect&pl=0) .

Comment: give me few hour to try this solution

Comment: Sure, take you time ..... :)

Comment: Hi Jayesh Patel can you tell me something, your solution is almost perfect, can I make this check on the Proceed to Cart button? For example if the user is not login to be redirect to customer/account/login/

Comment: anyway, thank you for your help, I solve this.